# Type and Class of Digital Certificates

Tags: cryptography, openssl, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I am using OpenSSL for implementing Digital Signatures.

As a part of the requirement I need to identify the Class of a certificate.
As far as I have read, the classes and types of a certificate are vendor specific.

However, I want to know if there is any way of identifying and retrieving such information
from an X509 Certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types and Classes are something that various CA invent mainly for marketing purposes. They have no definition within standards. Consequently you can't extract such information from the certificate.

In general, digital certificates are indeed different - they can be X.509 certificates, IPSec certificates (this seems to be a subset of X.509 certificates with extra requirements), attribute certificates (maybe I forgot something). They have different structure, but in real life you will deal only with X.509 certificates (Attribute Certificates become more widespread, but very slowly, and IPSec certs are almost never seen in wild).

Comment: thanks, I was not aware about certificates other than X509!
I just learnt that X509 has certain bit strings ('keyUsage' extension) to denote the uses of a certificate. May be that will help.

I hope similar info exists in other certificates too.

Comment: @sg1 key usage is just one criteria for "classifying" certificates. Verisign classifies them by Subject (owner of the key), Adobe if I understand it right calls certificates stored on hardware tokens "class 3 certificates" (or was it "type 3"?) etc. I.e. there's chaos in those classifications.

Comment: can you tell me where I can read about these other certificate types (IPSec and Attribute)? I could not find any material on them.

Comment: @sg1 Hmm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_certificate#Comparison_of_attribute_and_public_key_certificates . As for IPSec - see "IKE" here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737812%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Two important criteria for certificates are:

- what is intended for (mail encryption, signing applets, ...)
- what did the issuing authority check before signing the data

The latter one is typically termed "class". There seems some convention, that the higher numeric values assume more checking, so class 1 typically verifies, that the certificate holder has access to the mail address in the certificate, while a class 3 certificate may require the holder to provide his/her ID card at a given counter, so address data and identity may be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

**Classification of Classes**

Class 1- Binds an individual to a valid email address. A Certificate Authority will conduct an email challenge to validate the email address.

Class 2-Binds an individual to a valid email address plus additional information about the individual that is provided during the application process (Full Name, Company Name, and so forth) A Certificate Authority will use third party databases to verify the individuals identity information

Class 3- Binds an individual to the ownership of an email address and individual identity information using third party databases to verify plus identity verification via face-to-face appearance before a local vetting agent.

**You may check GlobalSign PersonalSign Certificate - Digital Certificate:**
https://www.globalsign.com/personalsign/comparison.html

You may identify the type or class of an X.509 certificate by looking at the certificate details of it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, the Class of a digital signatures is vendor specific and/or depends on the level of checking performed and their intention.
It is definitely not a part of X.509 certificate structure.

It may also depend on government guidelines.

Here in this [document on "Guidelines for Usage of Digital Signatures
in e-Governance"](http://egovstandards.gov.in/guidelines/Guidelines%20for%20Digital-signature/Guidelines_for_Usage_of_Digital_Signatures_in_e-Governance_-_v1.0_revised_sent_by_DIT.pdf/view) by Department of Information Technology, Government of India,
3 types of Classes for Digital signatures are explained on page 11.

The classification has been done on the basis of 2 factors:

1) Assurance Level

2) Applicability

and, it seems to go well with most international practices too.